# The use of the $\subseteq$ symbol in the definition of a compact subset

Tags: general-topology

My understanding is that any union of open sets is open - or most of the time, I invite someone to point the exceptions, if they exist. So why is characteristically used the $\subseteq$ symbol when stating that any open cover $A$ (an open set, by my understanding), in some topological space X, contains a subset $K$ of $X$ -- $K$ is closed and bounded, if $K$ is indeed compact -- in the following way $K\subseteq A$, if $K$ is closed and can never really be the result of an union of open sets?

Observation: I apologize if this question is by any means a duplicate. I tried to search for similar questions to this one, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Do you mean $\Subset$?

Comment: Doesn't $A \subseteq B$ mean that either $A \subset B$ or $A = B$ is true? So $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $A$ is equal to $B$.

Comment: In certain topological spaces, a set can be both open and closed at the same time. Example: $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ with the induced topology. There $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are both open and closed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here. First, if $\mathscr{A}$ is an open cover of $K$, we *don’t* say that $K\subseteq\mathscr{A}$: we say, correctly, that $K\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{A}$. A subset of $\mathscr{A}$ is some collection of open sets in $X$, and $K$ is certainly not that: it’s a collection of points in $X$. $K$ is, however, a subset of the *union* of the members of the cover $\mathscr{A}$.

Secondly, a union of open sets *can* be closed, and even compact. For a very simple example, consider the space $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with the discrete topology: every subset is open, so the compact set $\{1,2\}$ is the union of the open sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. For a more complicated example, let $X$ be the [middle-thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), considered as space in its own right with the topology that it inherits as a subspace of the real line. Let $K=\left[0,\frac13\right]\cap X$; then $K$ is both compact and an open subset of $X$.

Comment: Good clarifications. However, even in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and from what he wrote I think this is the space he is thinking about) someone might write $K\subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{A}$ even though in this case necessarily $K\neq \bigcup \mathscr{A}$. Some people just prefer $\subseteq$ over $\subset$.

Comment: @Cronus: Indeed; I’m one of them. After all, the general statement requires $\subseteq$, and $\subseteq$ is correct even when $\subsetneqq$ also happens to be true. (I don’t use $\subset$ at all, owing to its unfortunate ambiguity.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, since in general topological spaces you can't replace $\subseteq$ with $\subsetneq$. (I believe in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can). PS I'm in favor of $\subsetneq$; $\subsetneqq$ is too big.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. However, it is rather standard to write $K\subseteq A$ even when you know for certain that $K\neq A$ (which means you could have written $K\subset A$ or $K\subsetneq A$). It is just a matter of taste; many people will only write "$K\subset A$" (or $K\subsetneq A$) if the fact $K\neq A$ is relevant to the point being made.

I think this is what confused you, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** Oh, I understand your question a little bit better now. It is true that in some topological spaces a set can be compact an open, but considering what you wrote I assume you are thinking of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In any case I still think the main issue here is that people write $K\subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{A}$ (where $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of open sets) while they know $K\neq \bigcup \mathscr{A}$ since $\bigcup \mathscr{A}$ is open (because the union of open sets is indeed always open). And again, this is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes, I should have considered this in $\Re^n$ and explicitly said so. I am sorry. But @Brian M. Scott probably answered my question more thoroughly, since the use of the definition of open covers is a more general one and considers other metric spaces. I see how the use of the symbol is actually more adequate.

Comment: No need to be sorry :]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any every union of open sets is open, but you seem to have your definition of "compact" horribly garbled. The right definition should be something like:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $K\subseteq X$. Then $K$ is said to be **compact** if, for every family $\mathscr A$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $K\subseteq \bigcup_{S\in \mathscr A} S$, there is a *finite* $\mathscr B \subseteq \mathscr A$ such that $K\subseteq \bigcup_{S\in \mathscr B} S$.